# Subprocess calls acting differently in shell and interpretor

Tags: python, shell

When I run the following commands in Python interpreter, all is good, but fail when run as a script. Somehow the opened tunnel is not recognized. Any pointers will be appreciated.

**Interpreter:**

```
gateway = subprocess.Popen("ssh -N sshgw", shell=True)

scp_prod = "scp -r server:/NFS/{0} .".format(filePath)
subprocess.call(scp_prod, shell=True)

gateway.kill()
```

**Script:**

```
try:
  gateway = subprocess.Popen("ssh -N sshgw", shell=True)

  scp_prod = "scp -r server:/NFS/{0} .".format(filePath)
  subprocess.call(scp_prod, shell=True)
finally:  
  gateway.kill()
```

Comment: What about filePath? Is calculated at runtime? There are any error output?

Comment: What does "the opened tunnel is not recognized" mean? If there's an exception traceback, show us the traceback. If it gives the wrong output, tell us what output you expected and what you got. And so on.

Comment: Also, why are you using command-line strings with shell=True`? Do you really need the shell? If so, are you sure that your `$SHELL`/`%COMPSPEC%` is the same in both cases? And, more generally, how are you running the script? Just doing `python ./script` in the same shell session as you're starting the interactive interpreter in the other case, or something different?